# PEP 0008: What does the BDFL mean by 'in true XP style'?

Tags: python, coding-style

I was reading [PEP 0008 (the python style guide)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#a-foolish-consistency-is-the-hobgoblin-of-little-minds), and came across the following reason to *not* follow any rule in the style guide.

It says that it's ok to break a rule to

> be consistent with surrounding code that also breaks it (maybe for historic reasons) -- although this is also an opportunity to clean up someone else's mess (in true XP style).

What does 'in true XP style' mean?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_programming

Comment: top google hit for the expression: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/chennaipy/e84vhmo1jQU

Comment: .. and in this case it refers to refactoring some else's messy code. Try and leave this world a little better than you found it ;)

Comment: Is this seriously not a question worthy of answering in an answer?  I don't think 'XP' as an abbreviation for 'extreme programming' is so well heard of as to make this obvious to the point of down voting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, XP here refers to [Extreme Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_programming). I think the comment "an opportunity to clean up someone else's mess (in true XP style)" may be half tongue-in-cheek. While refactoring and design improvement are core practices in XP, many critics argue that it often leads to the same code needing to be rewritten several times.